# Remove all whitespace, except between quotes

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to find a way to remove white space from a specific place in a string but have yet to have any luck. I cant just use -Replace to get rid of all white spaces. Ideally I would like to define that everything outside of double quotes gets removed.

I am starting with a string like:

```
{     [     "Data: I have some data here",     "%somedata% == 1234"     ]     }
```

And I want it to end up like:

```
{["Data: I have some data here","%somedata% == 1234"]}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putting your string into $InStuff, this will replace any 2-or-more spaces with nothing. note that the `-replace` operator uses regex, while the `.Replace()` method does not.

```
$InStuff -replace ' {2,}', ''
```

output ...

```
["Data: I have some data here","%somedata% == 1234"]}
```

Comment: @NathanMedeiros - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]